# Is it possible to change start up logo of the monitor?

Tags: display, pictures

I guess the title speaks for the question itself.

When I turn on my monitor by clicking on the button attached in the bottom near its screen it shows me a logo, a stylized LG logo, in my case.

[image]

I've seen Windows startup logo modifications before, and I understand that operating system is different from monitor's internal software.

So I wonder if I can somehow change it and set my own custom picture as the greeting logo?

Comment: I think its possible like when you change ROM of Android And get another logo at startup. But its mean you need to find how to hack the ROM of your monitor. Perhaps get info with datasheet of your monitor ?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you really enjoy welding PCB boards, the answer is no, not really. Some of these monitors come with the option to edit the monitor splash screen in the on-board menu. Usually, the splash is there to cover the power on sequence of the monitor, so you don't have a black screen while it's powering up and syncing the video inputs.

Comment: Do you have any references at all?

Comment: https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/81593-monitor-splash-screen/ There are a few in Yahoo answers, but I don't count that as a credible source. There are also a number of LG manuals I paged through.

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to include that source. My comment was meant as suggestion to improve your answer.